# My centered layout “flips” a few pixels to the left when I change pages!! How to fix this?

Tags: html, css, centering

I made a very simple layout for an infographic, based on DIVs displayed inline. It is centered, and varies on height from page to page, but the structure of the pages are the same, the only thing that changes is image content. The width is the same in every page which is 680px, and the elements are always the same, always on the same position. I don’t know why the page flips as if the margin of the container DIV changed from page to page.

As shown in this picture:

http://andressa-casale.com.br/NV/flipping.jpg

Here is the base layout:

http://andressa-casale.com.br/NV/page_02.html

If anyone on could help me, I’d be really happy.

This is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center; 
    background: #FFF;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}


#container {
    width: 680px;
    margin:0 auto;          
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#box_menu {
    width: 680px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#mspace01 {
    width: 96px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
}

#mspace02 {
    width: 9px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
}

#mspace03 {
    width: 144px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
}

#bt01 {
    width: 124px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #62BD80;
}

#bt02 {
    width: 107px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #1083D2;
}

#bt03 {
    width: 91px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #F36851;
}

#bt04 {
    width: 91px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #F68B1F;
}

#box_info{
    width: 680px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#box_conteudo{
    width: 600px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#vvbt{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 53px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background: #FFF;

}
```

And this is the HTML structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Título</title>

<link type="text/css" media="all" href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>



<!--==============================================
Início do Body
============================================== -->
<body>
<!-- Início do Container -->
<div id="container">

    <!-- Início do Menu --> 
    <div id="box_menu">

      <div id="mspace01"></div>

          <div id="bt01"><img src="imgs/bt_01.jpg" width="124" height="37" /></div>

          <div id="mspace02"></div>

          <div id="bt02"><a href="page_02.html" target="_self"><img src="imgs/bt_02.jpg" width="107" height="37" /></a></div>

          <div id="mspace02"></div>

          <div id="bt03"><a href="page_03.html" target="_self"><img src="imgs/bt_03.jpg" width="91" height="37" /></a></div>

          <div id="mspace02"></div>

          <div id="bt04"><a href="page_04.html" target="_self"><img src="imgs/bt_04.jpg" width="91" height="37" /></a></div>

          <div id="mspace03"></div>

     </div>
     <!-- Fim do Menu --> 

     <!-- Início do Infográfico -->
     <div id="box_info">


          <!-- Início do VV BT 01 -->

          <div id="vvbt"></div>

          <!-- Fim do VV BT 01 -->





          <!-- Início do Box Conteudo -->
          <div id="box_conteudo">

               <img src="imgs/conteudo_01.jpg" width="600" height="1011" />

          </div>
          <!-- Início do Box Conteudo -->





          <!-- Início do VV BT 02 -->

          <div id="vvbt"><a href="page_02.html" target="_self"><img src="imgs/vai.jpg" width="40" height="40" /></a></div>

          <!-- Fim do VV BT 02 -->


     </div>
     <!-- Fim do Infográfico --> 

</div>
<!-- Fim do Container -->
</body>
<!--==============================================
Fim do Body
============================================== -->



</html>
```

Comment: Does the browser have the scrollbar in one and not the other?

Comment: It's funny how much space a scrollbar takes up, don't you think?

Comment: Lol...that damn scrollbar..

Comment: @dwhite.me Yes, in two of the pages the height is not big enough to start a scroll bar.

Comment: If it is the scrollbar, set your CSS to html{min-height:101%;} and that should fix it.

Comment: It's funny because it happens both on chrome and firefox, but in IE it works just fine.

Comment: @dwhite.me gonna try this, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Please mark my answer below as correct then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
html{
  min-height:101%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your link works fine for me. This is almost certainly caused by your browser scrollbar toggling on and off. i.e. when your `#box-conteudo` container is taller than the height of the browser, the vertical scrollbar appears, thus pushing the container into a slightly smaller area. Try giving your `#box-conteudo` a min-height that is at least the height of the browser.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in the min-height indeed. But I did as @dwhite.me told me to, and it worked. It was on the html and not on #box-conteudo. Thanks a lot for your answer! =D